# How to use lead() and lag() on varchar2 fields?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, analytics, sliding-window, varchar2

**Oracle 11g**
[My work so far on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5224c/1)

I'm using **lead()** and **lag()** functions on varchar2 columns.
Using the following rules, I'd like to generate the desired results.

1. If  lag_val is null then '('
2. If  lag_val is same as set_a then 'and'
3. If  lag_val != set_a then 'or'
4. If  lead_val is null then ')'

I get 'invalid number' when I use nvl() to convert null values so I can compare.

**Desired Output**

```
   SEQNO SET_A LAG_VAL  LEAD_VAL  MENU_ENTRY
   ------------------------------------------
   1      CAKE  <null>  CAKE      (
   2      CAKE  CAKE    BEER      AND
   3      BEER  CAKE    BRATS     OR
   4      BRATS BEER    <null>    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the "-" operator on strings, not with lead/lag.  I think you want this:

```
select  seqno,
         set_a,
         lag_val,
         lead_val
    , case 
    when (lag_val ) is null then '('
    when (lead_val ) is null then ')'
    when (lag_val = set_a) then 'and'    
    else  'or'
    end  as menu_entry
from ( select seqno, 
        set_a, 
        lag(set_a,1) over (order by seqno) as lag_val,
--        lag(to_number,'XX') over (order by seqno) as lag_val,
        lead(set_a,1) over (order by seqno) as lead_val       
 from menu_items)
order by seqno
```